# No puedo usar la dependencia fl_chart en conjunto con flutter_svg

Tags: flutter, dependencias

Este es un SDK muy nuevo pero, tengo la esperanza de que alguien con experiencia pueda ayudarme. Estoy usando Flutter para crear una aplicación. Al ejecutar `flutter --version`, la consola me muestra la siguiente versión:

***Flutter 2.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git


Framework • revision c5a4b4029c (9 days ago) • 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800


Engine • revision 40441def69


Tools • Dart 2.12.0***

Quiero integrar las siguientes dependencias flutter_svg y fl_chart en sus últimas versiones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando los agrego en las dependencias en el archivo pubspec.yaml y ejecuto "automáticamente al guardar" pub get: running (VS Code) me arroja el siguiente resultado en la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo por el mensaje que las versiones son incompatibles, pero no importa cuánto intente hacer que funcionen juntas en el mismo proyecto, no puedo encontrar una solución. Alguien con experiencia podría decirme cómo solucionarlo, qué versiones tendría que usar con esta versión de Flutter. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer ya estás usando Flutter 2.0 y null safety activado, entonces necesitas que las dependencias también estén actualizadas a null-safety, en el caso de `fl_chart` ya está migrada en stable `0.20.1`, solo necesitas apuntar a la nueva versión de `flutter_svg`.

En lugar de `flutter_svg: ^0.19.3` usa:

`flutter_svg: ^0.21.0-nullsafety.0`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Esto me soluciono el problema.

Comment: que bueno, te invito a mi canal para cosas más avanzadas de flutter :)  www.youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: Ahí estaré! Gracias!